# Adding an outgoing caller IDs returns `failed` regardless of success

Tags: php, twilio

I am adding a phone number to Manage Caller IDs list using the PHP SDK. When I do this, Twilio will response with the validation code and call the phone, as expected. I enter the number and the (automated) caller states that the number has successfully been added. The number also appears in the Managed Caller IDs list as being verified.

However the response from the Twilio API call has the VerficationStatus set to `failed`. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue myself.  I am developing a new application and can verify that it was working correctly last week.  I am going to submit a ticket and will update here with any info.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has responded to the ticket that I submitted, and fixed the issue on their end. I have verified that their api is returning 'success' when the number has been correctly validated.

Comment: What was the response? It is still not working for me and my ticket has been unanswered for two days.

Comment: They responded to my ticket immediately, saying they made a "change" on their end.  I assumed that was a global change, however re-reading the response from them, I guess it could have been pertaining just to my account.

Comment: Mine is fixed now also. It seems to be a fix made per account until the greater issue is resolved.